# Component render twice with a reselect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reselect

The following `selectManageAdvancedUserFilters` selector cause to render my component twice, but without that selector it renders only one time

```
export const selectManageAdvancedUserFilters = typeCode => {
  return createSelector([selectUserFilters(typeCode)], userFilters => {
    const manageAdvancedFilters = userFilters.map((filter, index) => {
      return {
        index: index + 1,
        label: filter.name,
        value: filter.name,
        id: filter.id
      };
    });
    return manageAdvancedFilters;
  });
};

export const selectUserFilters = typeCode => {
  return createSelector([selectAllUserFilters], allUserFilters =>
    allUserFilters.filter(allUserFilter => allUserFilter.type === typeCode)
  );
};

export const selectAllUserFilters = createSelector(
  [selectControls],
  controls => {
    return controls && controls.advancedFilters ? controls.advancedFilters : [];
  }
);


export const selectControls = state => {
  return state.controls.data;
};
```

here is the usage of selector

```
const unallocatedFilters = useSelector(
    selectDropdownSuggestionFilters('AF1')
  )
```

What is the reason cause to rerender with this selector?

Answer (score 0):

I think the re-render is caused by the implementation details of the dynamic parameter, `typeCode`.

See the link below:
https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/issues/392